# Disable AutoResize of Asp.Net ReportView Control

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using `ReportViewer` control in my MVC application. Basically there is a `ReportViewerWebForm.aspx` file that gets loaded as `iFrame` on the view.
Problem is, it dynamically sets the `width` and `height` of the iframe. I can see a `resizeIframe` js Function which sets the height and width of iframe
according to the document size. My question is, is there some property that can help me control the size of the iFrame in which this report and its content are loading? I want the iFrame to be of fixed width and height.

ReportViewerWebForm.aspx looks like this:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="ReportViewerForMvc" Name="ReportViewerForMvc.Scripts.PostMessage.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```